# React-Native _this5.setState is not a function when changing the text in TextInput?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am currently learning React-Native so apologies if the answer has appeared else where. But in my app whenever I change the text in the TextInput the program will crash with the error `_this5.setState is not a function`

i.e. if I search for 'Hello', everything works fine. But the moment when I change 'Hello' to 'Hell' the program crashes with that error.

Here's my code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      apiKey: 'insertMyAPIKey',
      isLoading: true,
      text: ''
    }
    this.setInputState = this.setInputState.bind(this)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Search For Summoner!"
          value={this.state.text}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
            text: text
          })}
          clearButtonMode="while-editing"
        />
        <Button 
          onPress={() => {
            this.MyFunctionsToRun(this.state.text)
          }}
          title="Search"
          color="#841584"
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 20}}>
          Searching for summoner: {this.state.text}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          The summoner ID: {this.state.summonerID}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          The summoner Rank: {this.state.leagueName}, {this.state.tier} {this.state.rank}, {this.state.leaguePoints}
        </Text>
        <Text>
          The Summoner Win Rate: {this.state.winRate}
        </Text>
        <View>
          <FlatList 
            data={this.state.lastTenGames}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.lane}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
onChangeText={text => (this.state.text = text)}
```

or use another function

```
onChangeText={this.changeText}

changeText = text => {
    this.setState({text: text});
};
```

i hope it works for you :D

Comment: thanks for your feed back. The first method doesn't work. When I begin typing the app crashes with 'Cannot set property of 'text' of undefined'. The second method looks like it's just moving my function from within the {} to outside of it.